# postfix after queue not working

Tags: postfix

I'm trying to play with the postfix after queue. Basically, I want to see if I can modify outgoing email. (I'm not interested at all in incoming email).
I did the following (based on http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html) :

1. launch ec2 on aws (ubuntu 16.04)
2. install postfix
3. created filter with user filter
4. modify the master.cf by adding the -o content_filter=filter:dummy

   smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd -o content_filter=filter:dummy
5. add the filter service definition at the end of the master.cf file

   filter    unix  -       n       n       -       10      pipe
       flags=Rq user=filter null_sender=
       argv=/home/ubuntu/run_filter.sh -f ${sender} -- ${recipient}
6. Send email using

   echo "hello world" | mail -s "second message" ...@gmail.com

But the filter is not called. And the email is sent without any change.

It seems like I'm missing something very basic. If someone can help, thanks!

Comment: Did you check the log?

Comment: When you do that `echo "hello world" | mail -s "second message" ...@gmail.com`, what happens  in `/var/log/mail.log` ?

Comment: Have you reloaded Postfix? Again: show the logs!

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your `php.ini` isn't referencing the correct path to sendmail.

You can check your `php.ini` file or apache logs to confirm this.

Alternatively, you can use the absolute path instead:

```
echo "Subject: test" | /usr/sbin/sendmail test@example.com
```

you can also confirm the registered path from command line:

```
which sendmail
```

Good Luck :)

Comment: Maybe you could explain why trying that would make a difference.

Comment: Sorry, As you can see I'm quite new around here. I'll edit my answer now with further clarification.

Comment: Thanks Max.  That's a much nicer answer.  Good luck to you too.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong as I don't know exactly your setup, but I think that `mail` does not send messages through `smtp`.
You can check postfix logs, if your message is received via `postfix/smtpd` or via `postfix/pickup`.

You can configure mail to use smtp I think, depends what `mail` you have installed (mailx, nail etc).

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't answer directly your question, but could help you more on long term.

When I have an application that I expect to do something, I am using tracing tools like `strace`, `tcpdump`/`wireshark`, `perf`, `systemtap`.

In your case, because I expect `mail` to connect via a TCP or at least an Unix socket to send the email, I would run it under `strace`.

```
echo "hello world" | strace -f -e network mail -s "second message" ...@gmail.com
```

`-f` = follow child processes too.

`-e network` = trace only network related system calls. You may use `-e file` to see which files are used. For more details see [strace(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) man page